# Concatenating two columns

Tags: r

I have two data frames. They are

```
x <- data.frame(sulfur = c(NA, 5, 7, NA, NA), nitrate = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 7))
y <- data.frame(sulfur = c(NA, 3, 7, 9, NA), nitrate = c(NA, NA, NA, 6, 7))
```

I want a new data frame which should be like

```
z <- data.frame(sulfur(NA, 5, 7, NA, NA, NA, 3, 7, 9, NA), nitrate=c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 7, NA, NA, NA, 6, 7))
```

I am trying two join columns and make it a single data frame.                How do I do it?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot rbind() works perfectly.

Comment: But it has to be noted that column names should be same to make rbind work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 df<-data.frame(Sulfur=c(NA,5,7,NA,NA), Nitrate = c(NA,NA,NA,3,7))
df2<-data.frame(Sulfur=c(NA,3,7,9,NA), Nitrate = c(NA,NA,NA,6,7))

df3<-(rbind(df,df2))

>df3
     Sulfur Nitrate
1      NA      NA
2       5      NA
3       7      NA
4      NA       3
5      NA       7
6      NA      NA
7       3      NA
8       7      NA
9       9       6
10     NA       7
```

Answer (score 0):

Other options include, placing the datasets in a `list` and then use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(x,y))
```

---

or we can use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(x,y)
```

NOTE: The above two functions can be applied to more than 2 datasets.

Answer (score 0):

```
> class(lst)
[1] list    
> dplyr::rbind_all(lst)
> do.call(lst,rbind)
```

You can use above function since it can apply on multiple (more than two) data frames.